# Variance of Bernoulli whose probability depends on n

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $(X_i)_i^n$ be $i.i.d$ Bernoulli random variables such that $X_i^{(n)} = 1$ with probability $\frac{\lambda}{n}$ and $0$ otherwise. Find the expected value and variance of the sum $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^{(n)}$.

My attempt:
The expected value is $E[S_n] = E[\sum X_i^{(n)}] = \sum E[X_i^{(n)}] = n*\frac{\lambda}{n} = \lambda$. I think this is correct (and rather straightforward). However, I have a problem with variance.

Approach 1: $Var(S_n) = Var(\sum X_i^{(n)}) = \sum Var(X_i^{(n)}) = n*(\frac{\lambda}{n})*(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}) = \lambda(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})$.

Approach 2: $Var(S_n) = E[S_n^2] - E^2[S_n] = E[(\sum X_i^{(n)})^2] - \lambda^ 2 = nE[(X_i^{(n)})^2]- \lambda^2 = n*\frac{\lambda}{n} - \lambda^2 = \lambda(1-\lambda) $

The two approaches give different answers for variance. One of them must be wrong. Which is it and why?

Comment: First correct (and more appropriate), second wrong. $(\sum X_i^{(n)})^2\neq\sum (X_i^{(n)})^2$

Comment: Since $X_i^{(n)}$s are $i.i.d$, don't we have $(\sum X_i^{(n)})^2 = \sum (X_i^{(n)})^2$ in expectation?

Comment: No. Also note that LHS can take value $n^2$ and RHS at most $n$.

Comment: @ForumWhiner your equality is only true if the expected value of the random variables is $0$, which is not true in this case.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Ah ha! That's where I went wrong. Thanks.